# Hibernate JPA - No Persistence provider for EntityManager error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to connect to sql server using JPA and hibernate with an Eclipse Maven project. I've tried moving the persistence.xml file to various locations but it doesn't seem to help.

My persistence.xml file is

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="Trades" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"    value="jdbc:sqlserver:/Trades\SQL00;databaseName=Trades" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="dev" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
      <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and my code is as follows and is located in src/main/resources/META-INF

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Trades");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I have attached a screenshot which shows my eclipse set up

[image]

Comment: try changing the provider in your persistence.xml to `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` if you don't mind using spring, i can give you a working setup. i think you are not using the newest hibernate version as in the latest version there is no need for an `EntityManagerFactory`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I am using Hibernate 5.2.10. Regarding EntityManagerFactory, I was just following some articles on the net - what should I be using instead?

Comment: i prefer to use the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`  with the`org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource` property

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, turned out that Maven must have downloaded corrupt libraries - I was alerted this when I was unable to view the source for some classes in the Hibernates jars. I deleted the jars in my .m2 directory and when the jars were refreshed, it worked fine. A bit of tricky one.